# What's the correct way to convert from StringBuilder to String?

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

From what I've seen online, people seem to suggest that the toString() method is to be used, however the documentation states:

*Creates a String representation of this object. The default representation is platform dependent. On the java platform it is the concatenation of the class name, "@", and the object's hashcode in hexadecimal.*

So it seems like using this method might cause some problems down the line?

There is also mkString and result(). The latter of which seems to make the most sense. But I'm not sure what the differences between these 3 methods are and if that's how result() is supposed to be used.

Comment: `toString` calls `result`. They are the same. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.scala#L97

Comment: @texasbruce They "are" the same *right now*. But the implementation might change over time. And `result()` guarantees to return the constructed string, whereas the `toString` might as well return something like `StringBuilder("foo bar baz... [1023034024 characters omitted]")` if the core library maintainers decide that it's more useful or just easier to read in the debug messages.

Comment: I'm just noticing that it's a surprisingly good question. It highlights the difference between intensional and extensional descriptions: extensionally, both `toString` and `result` currently contain the same implementation. But intensionally, the `toString` is characterized as "whatever seems to be most pleasant to read", whereas `result` is characterized as "the thing that returns the built string". The intensional definitions are different, but should not vary over time, whereas the extensional ones happen to currently coincide, but can in principle drift apart over time.

Comment: Although I agree with the whole `intent relevance of result` and `implementation relevance of toString` but if we use this logic of `may change` then implementation of any method which we rely on may change. This is exactly what the library stability means and is foundation of basic trust. Java standard library being a really stable library, I don't   see any chances of this ever happening.

Comment: Even projects like Scala compiler, Guava rely on this `toString`.

Comment: @sarveshseri "Guava rely on this `toString`" - You surely did not mean that Guava somehow relies on a particular implementation of `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.toString`? If not, then what did you mean?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, `StringBuilder::toString()` is used at many places in Guava.

Comment: And yes, although these are instances of Java StringBuilder. Scala `StringBuilder::result()` just delegates to Java StringBuilder `toString`. Why should Scala ever choose to come up with a different `toString` method?

Comment: @sarveshseri "yes, `StringBuilder::toString()` is used at many places in Guava" - I guarantee you that Guava does not use `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder` anywhere, because it does not rely on Scala in any way. Please take into the account that the question is tagged with `[scala]`, not `[java]`.

Comment: @sarveshseri "Scala `StringBuilder::result()` just delegates to Java `StringBuilder toString`. Why should Scala ever choose to come up with a different toString method?" - That's some implementation detail. The question was not about implementation details, but about what method to use. Since their implementation is the same anyway, the only distinguishing factor is the clarity of the intent. The `toString` method says "give me a human-readable representation of the current state of the builder", whereas the `result` says "give me the result of building the string". The latter is what we want.

Comment: And, yes, it is of course true that `StringBuilder.toString` in any JVM language has a very strong tradition of returning the currently constructed string. However, I don't accept the premise that everyone who is trying to use Scala has also to learn 25 years of Java history with all its traditions and conventions. Just look at this comment thread here: we are discussing implementation details of some unrelated library (guava) for some different language (java). Who except old-school java veterans is even supposed to follow the discussion, and why should it even matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `toString` implementation currently just redirects to the `result` method anyway, so those two methods will behave in the same way. However, they express slightly different intent:

- `toString` requests a textual representation of `StringBuilder`s current state that is ["concise but informative (and) that is easy for a person to read"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). So, theoretically, the (vague) specification of this method does not forbid abbreviating the result, or enhancing conciseness and readability in any other way.
- `result` requests the actual constructed string. No different readings seem possible here.

Therefore, if you want to obtain the resulting string, use `result` to express your intent as clearly as possible.

In this way, the reader of your code won't have to wonder whether `StringBuilder.toString` might shorten something for the sake of "conciseness" when the string gets over 9000 kB long, or something like that.

The `mkString` is for something else entirely, it's mostly used for interspersing separators, as in `"hello".mkString(",") == "h,e,l,l,o"`.

Some further links:

- The paragraph with "hashcode in hexadecimal" describes *the default*. It is just [documentation inherited from `AnyRef`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/AnyRef.html), because the creator of `StringBuilder` didn't bother to provide more detailed documentation.
- If you [look into code, you'll see that `toString` is actually just delegating to `result`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9468b9abcda6955688804194c02fe11db8c78a38/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.scala#L97).
- The [documentation of `StringBuilder`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.html) also mentions `result()` in the introductory overview paragraph.

Just use `result()`.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; use `result` as stated in the [**docs**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.html).

`toString` MUST never be called in anything at all for another purpose other than a quick debug.

`mkString` is inherited from collections hierarchy and it will basically create another `StringBuilder` so is very inefficient.

Comment: Although I get the sentiment that it "should" be avoided. When projects like Scala compiler, Scala standard lib, Guava, slf4j, log4j2, Akka, Finagle, cats, cats-effect, http4s, doobie use `toString`, you can not really safeguard your real world project by not using `toString` in your code.

Comment: @sarveshseri care to point out where libraries like **cats** or the stdlib use the `toString` method for something important?

Comment: Check `StringMonoid` in cats. There are too many instance in stdlib, you will find many (I noticed 10 at a cursory glance) instances in just `StringOps.scala` itself. For example - Check `WithFilter::map(f: Char => Char): String`, `WithFilter::flatMap(f: Char => String): String`.

Comment: And yes, although these are instances of Java StringBuilder. Scala `StringBuilder::result()` just delegates to Java StringBuilder's `toString`. Why should Scala ever choose to come up with a different toString method? And I don't understand, why this `result()` was even introduced to further confuse everybody? And why even our stdlib does not use our own `StringBuilder`? Why was this Scala `StringBuilder` even created? All these desgin/usage decisions are another discussion.

Comment: @sarveshseri I think you misunderstood my comment, I mean on `toString` in general, on any class, it MUST never be used. The fact that the **Java** `StringBuilder` decided to use `toString` to produce the result is just a bad design decision that couldn't be fixed due maintaining backwards compatibility _(something very common in **Java**)_ - And since **Scala's** `StringBuilder` is just a wrapper of the **Java** one, it makes sense that performance-sensitive code would use the **Java** one to avoid an extra allocation. And **Scala** introduced its own one so it can behave like a collection.